# socket io really heavy load

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My nodejs server under heavy load for some reason, all i'm running is a small app using socket io. This app mainly gets text from a textarea on an html page and updates it to the people in the "room". Sort of like a live chat. However this is causing huge load on my server every time someone types something if theres 2 clients per room it will cause a lag spike.

server-side code

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join_room',function(room){
        socket.join(room);
        socket.in(room).emit('joined_room', 'true');
    });

    socket.on('blob', function (room) {
        socket.in(room.name).emit('new_text', room.update_text);
    });

    socket.on('blob-typing',function(room){
            socket.in(room.name).emit('some_typing', {cur_loc:room.cursor_location});
    });
});
```

client-side code

```
var socket = io.connect('x');
socket.emit('join_room',url_key);

setInterval(function(){
    if (field_change === true) {
        var post_data = {
            name: url_key,
            update_text: $('.blob').val()
        };
        socket.emit('blob', post_data);

        post_data = {
        name: url_key,
        cursor_location:0
        };
        socket.emit('blob-typing', post_data);
    }
    field_change = false;
},1000);

$(".blob").on('keyup paste input',function () {
    delay(function(){
        field_change = true;
    },500);
});

socket.on('joined_room',function(data){

});

var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

Please advise as to how i can fix the load, any technique or strategy would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i fix the load? and why would it cause this much load its just text going back and forth @Amstell